# C# inherited class from generic as a type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I've got an issue with generics. I've those classes :

```
abstract class BaseTestClass<T> : where T : class, new()
{
   //base test class implementation
   public abstract void Run(BaseDataClass<T> data);
}

class BaseDataClass<T> : where T : class, new()
{
   //base data class implementation
}

class DataA : BaseDataClass<SettingsA>
{
   //some stuff
}

class TestA : BaseTestClass<SettingsA>
{
   //Works!
   public override void Run(BaseDataClass<SettingsA> data)
   {
   }
   //Doesn't Work!
   public override void Run(DataA data)
   {
   }

}
```

My question if why can't I use the inherited class in the abstract method ?

[EDIT]
The error at compilation is:

> TestA does not implement inherited abstract member Run(BaseDataClass)

Comment: What do you mean by "Why can't I use the inherited class...?". Is there a compilte time exception?

Comment: *You can not use*  means you get a compile error? If yes, which one?

Comment: Overridden methods can't change the signature of the original method.

Comment: The method definition has to match, but you can of course pass `DataA` object into `BaseDataClass<SettingsA>` method parameter.

Comment: _"Doesn't Work"_ - is not particularly helpful.  Consider adding the compile error we suspect you are getting and it will help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this with an additional generic argument, Type-Safe and without cast:

```
internal abstract class BaseTestClass<T, Y>
    where T : class, new()
    where Y : BaseDataClass<T>
{
    private T m_data;

    //base test class implementation
    public abstract void Run(Y data);
}

public class BaseDataClass<T> where T : class, new()
{
}


internal class TestA : BaseTestClass<SettingsA, DataA>
{
    public override void Run(DataA data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class DataA : BaseDataClass<SettingsA>
{    
}

class SettingsA
{
}
```

This is type-safe because the constraint is

```
where Y : BaseDataClass<T>
```

If you don't need T directly in you base class, you can only use one generic parameter and remove T

Comment: The most helpful answer. I did it for lots of other parameters, so why not with the data parameter... thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You can, but the `BaseTestClass<SettingsA>` base class simply does NOT have a method to override of the signature `Run(DataA)`, but only one of the signature `Run(BaseDataClass<DataA>)`.

The generic inheritance also means that the generic T type is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your second method does not compile because there is no method to be overriden by it, removing the `override` modificator will make your code compile.

If you want to have a method which will run only when the parameter is of type DataA, but still execute the interface method implementation, you can do this way:

```
class TestA : BaseTestClass<SettingsA>
{
   //Works!
   public override void Run(BaseDataClass<SettingsA> data)
   {
   }

   public void Run(DataA data)
   {
       //dp some stuff
       Run((BaseDataClass<SettingsA>)data);
   }

}
```

But note that this is not bullet proof, you could miss boxed calls, the better way is do this way:

```
class TestA : BaseTestClass<SettingsA>
{
   //Works!
   public override void Run(BaseDataClass<SettingsA> data)
   {
        var myDataA = data as DataA;
        if (myDataA != null)
        {
            //your parameter is a DataA;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: The example I gave is a dummy one. My class is a little more complicated so that I do not have to cast to `DataA`. My point was, as the `DataA` class is also a `BaseDataClass<SettingsA>`, why does the compiler refuses it ?

Comment: it refuses because you can override a method only once..., if you still want to have a separate method to the method when it's explitictly called with a DataA parameter you must go with the first code.

Comment: And even tough you keep only the second method, you can't implement the abstract method with it because it explicit say you must support any BaseDataClass<T> and not only a subset of it (DataA).

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you cannot override one method with two methods.  Take the override off of one of the methods in TestA, and it will all work.  There's no point in overriding a single method twice, anyhow, within a single class.

Comment: 2nd doesn't work because of "override".  There's nothing for it to override.

Comment: Adding that in your answer will make your answer better.